A hash function that maintains mathematical equality (especially for sets)
I'm working on a little math-based programming language (written in Rust) that uses sets instead of types. In it, a variable or value belongs to a set of values (eg. x : {1, 2, 3} or msg : Str). The user can create finite sets (eg. x = {1, 2, 3, false, "hi"}), which store the values internally in a HashSet, with the values being hashed. However, the language also has a notion of infinite sets, like Nat, Int, Real, Complex, Str, etc. My problem is that I do not know how to optimally represent these infinite sets when inside another set (ie. through hashing).
My current idea is to set the hash of eg. Nat to be 0, Int to be 1, and so on, but that just feels wrong. Additionally, an expression that evaluates to an equivalent set should have the same hash and one that evaluates to a different set would have to have a different hash, so my current implementation wouldn't work:
// Reals except those that are Ints
A = Real \ Int
// hash of A should vary from the hash of Real and Int (what would its hash be though?)
B = Real \ A
// hash of B should be the same as hash of Int

In this example, it could be possible to somehow simplify, though in more complex expressions I don't know if they could always be simplified into something with an equal hash. Also, for A, using my method, I have no idea how the hash would be calculated.
My question is: is there some hash function that I should use that has this functionality, or is there some other algorithm or datastructure that I should be using to implement this, or am I completely off-track here and should be implementing the whole thing in a different way?

"a different set would have to have a different hash" - you can't avoid hash collisions if the things you're hashing can be of any size.

@kmdreko Of course, but ideally it would be rare

That describes most hashing functions. Here's a thought; don't rely on hashing but rather intern your sets so you can use simple identity comparisons.

@kmdreko How would that work with expressions of sets? And how would I store them inside a HashSet if I can't hash it? Edit: I was thinking, perhaps instead of storing the infinite set in another set, I store a reference to the interned value. That would emulate the behavior, right?

Maybe the XOR operation would help, since it has property a == b ^ (b ^ a), something similar to what you want.

I'm not sure how far you plan to do, but you fundamentally cannot represent set theoretic mathematics this way. The standard approach is to choose a language and a theory on top of that, and postulate it in your language. For instance, you could choose first order logic set theory, with ZFC as the theory. You can take a look at how proof assistants do it.

Frame Challenge: this is not about hashing, this is about canonicalization.
Hashing (or interning) takes an input and assign an integer value to it. If you want guaranteed equal hashes/interning, then you need to provide guaranteed equal inputs in the first place.
Your problem, therefore, is to create an algorithm that will produce a canonical form for any input. In the example given:
A = Real \ Int => Real \ Int
B = Real \ A => Int

Then, hashing or interning the canonical form will lead to an integer equal to all "canonically equal" sets -- no matter the hash/interning algorithm used.

Would you say it's relatively simple to implement this, or would I have essentially make some kind of CAS?

@Apuji: I would say the difficulty will depend on the set of operations to be supported. So far it looks relatively simple from what you have presented, but I don't know whether you presented all operations or not.

@Matthiew I'm planning, on allowing for union (|), intersection (&), exclusion/set minus (), symmetric difference (~), complement (!), power?? (Real^2 = [Real, Real]), and arbritrary mapping (eg. {x^2 where x : Nat}).
I think for the first few operations, I can just have an internal table of operations that reduce (eg. A | A = A, A & {} = {}, A | (B & C) = (A | B) & (A | C), etc.), and then simplify as much as possible. However, I don't really know how to work it with arbitrary mappings.

@Apuji: I think arbitrary mapping, or arbitrary sets, should remain as is in a first step. That is, {x^2 where x : Nat} would be equal to itself... and that's it. Similarly, {1, 2, 3} would be equal to itself. Then you only need to reason in terms of set & set operations, and never in terms of the individual elements of the set... and hopefully it's good enough.

@Matthiew Yeah, that does seem like the best solution. Though I then wonder how they will work when computing operations between them? For example: {x^3 where x : Int} \ Nat.
Edit: Perhaps, that could result in another "arbitrary set:" {x^3 where x : Int && x^3 !: Nat}?
